# Does Twilio Verify scrutinize phone numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Does the Twilio Verify API apply any level of scrutiny to the phone numbers it verifies or does it simply send and certify passcodes? The TeleSign Score API, for example, scores phone numbers (from 0 to 1,000) on how "trusted" it thinks the number is. Does Twilio's Verify API return any sort of data about the numbers it verifies or apply its own filter behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not.

Verify's capabilities are explained here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify.